# XmlPullParserException: expected START_TAG on ksoap2, but result shows just fine

Tags: android, xml, soap, android-ksoap2

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title. Searching through this site and other sites indicate that it is because of faulty NAMESPACE or URL values, but they are all fine. Also, when I use debug mode and dump the xml returned by the server, the response is just fine and looks exactly like the result in SoapUI. The code is pasted below; it's a long bit.

It uses two different Soap calls, because the first one only returns an ID which the second one converts to a username.

```
public Object doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String email = params[0];
        String password = params[1];

        //Soap variabelen voor de visitList
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "getVisitList");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = false; 
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL); 

        //Soap variabelen klaarzetten voor de username
        SoapObject usernameRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "getUser");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope usernameEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        usernameEnvelope.dotNet = false;

        HttpTransportSE usernameTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        usernameTransport.debug = true;
        try{
            List<HeaderProperty> headerlist = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
            headerlist.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode((email+":"+password).getBytes())));

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope, headerlist);

            Vector<SoapObject> response = (Vector<SoapObject>)envelope.getResponse();

            for(int i = 0; i<response.size(); i++)
            {
                SoapObject tempObject = response.get(i);
                if(tempObject != null)
                {
                    Visit tempVisit = new Visit();
                    tempVisit.setId(Integer.parseInt(tempObject.getProperty("ID").toString()));
                    tempVisit.setArrival(tempObject.getProperty("Arrival").toString());
                    tempVisit.setDuration(Integer.parseInt(tempObject.getProperty("Duration").toString()));
                    tempVisit.setReason(tempObject.getProperty("Reason").toString());

                    //Haal de username op met een soap request
                    PropertyInfo userid_pi = new PropertyInfo();
                    userid_pi.setName("ID");
                    userid_pi.setValue(tempObject.getProperty("UserID"));
                    userid_pi.setType(Integer.class);

                    usernameRequest.addProperty(userid_pi);
                    usernameEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(usernameRequest);
                    usernameTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, usernameEnvelope, headerlist);
                    SoapObject usernameResponse = (SoapObject)usernameEnvelope.getResponse();

                    tempVisit.setUser(usernameResponse.getProperty("Name").toString());

                    result.add(tempVisit);
                }
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e;
        }
    }
```

This is the xml returned by the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:tns="urn:DuocastAPI">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getUserResponse xmlns:ns1="DuocastAPI/">
        <User xsi:type="tns:User">
            <ID xsi:type="xsd:int">2208</ID>
            <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Lorem</Name>
            <CompanyName xsi:type="xsd:string">Ipsum</CompanyName>
            <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">lorem@ipsum.net</Email>
            <PassPort xsi:type="xsd:string"></PassPort>
            <IDCard xsi:type="xsd:string">#number here#</IDCard>
            <DriversLicense xsi:type="xsd:string"></DriversLicense>
            <Phone xsi:type="xsd:string">+12345678</Phone>
            <StorageArea xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</StorageArea>
            <GuidedAccess xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</GuidedAccess>
        </User>
    </ns1:getUserResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The error message is displayed here:

```
01-05 12:38:21.437: W/System.err(2324): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected:
   START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG (empty)
<br>@1:7 in     java.io.InputStreamReader@41f94798)
```

Comment: There's no closing tag on the Envelope node?  not even a />

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. The tag is actually there, but I failed in copy-pasting. Also the error says START_TAG, not END_TAG so that's not it.

Comment: I didn't even fail. It was there, but StackOverflow didn't display it.

Comment: I've put this envelope directly to parse method of SoapSerializationEnvelope and was parsed correctly...

Comment: Check if is this env that on wchich it failed - or maybe failed on next?

Comment: It's definately this envelope. The error code's line number corresponds to the line that calls this envelope.

Comment: But it's a loop. So error may occur in same line but in any next pass. Check with debugger or print to log i variable.

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel I would step through the code.  There are a few settings on the xmlpulparser that might solve the issue.  Don't give up the xmlpullparser can be wicked fast when used correctly.

Comment: Well, it's a loop indeed, but my test data uses the same input in each iteration... It's basically a table with appointments, and the failing API call translates a userid to a username. The userid is 2208 in every single row of the table...